# who can help to explain what is wrong in my code..counting sort of array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, counting

here I wrote a code which sorts arrays but something is wrong and I dont understand what is wrong please explain me..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int array[], int length){

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout << array[i];
    cout << endl;
}

/* min and max values which are the first and the last elements of the array*/
void countingSort(int array[], int length){

    int max = array[0];
    int min = array[0];
    int count[max - min + 1] = {};
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
        else
            min = array[i];
    }
    /* the new array with indexes*/
    for (int i = 0; i < max - min + 1; i++){
        count[array[i]]++;  
    }

    for (int j = 0;j < max - min;j++)
    {
        while(count[j] --) 
        array[sum++] = j;           
    }
}

int main() {

    int array[] = {4,7,8,9,10,6};
    countingSort(array, 6);
    printArray(array,6);
    return 0;
}
```

it have to sort the arrays through indexes

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Radik Harutyunyan  Firdt of all C++ does not support Variable Length Arrays. Some compilers have their one language extentions that support Variable Length Arrays However this declaration does not make sense  int count[max - min + 1] = {}; because there is declared an array that conntinns only one element.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it does not help

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = array[0];
```

This sets `max` to the **first** element of the array, not the last one. So when this line of code runs:

```
int count[max - min + 1] = {};
```

`count` always has a size of 1.

Change it to:

```
int max = array[length - 1];
```

Also, C++ does **not** support *Variable Length Arrays*; there are only some compilers that have extended their support for it. The size of the array must be a fixed constant at the time of compilation for these compilers. If you want to use VLAs, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I put int max = array[0] to find the max  value of the array

Comment: @RadikHarutyunyan Well, in that case, max is always equal to min, as in `int max = array[0];` and `int min = array[0]`, you set them both to the same value.

Comment: I have checked it returns the max and min elements int the array

Comment: @RadikHarutyunyan Does the compiler provide any error messages?

Comment: not any error((

Comment: Its just logic errors then. I can't compile your code as I am on an iPad, but take a look at @molbdnilo's answer. He/she has pointed out some logic errors that you can fix.

Comment: I improved it i puted it here you can see

Answer (score 1):

The function `countingSort` has around 50% lines with bugs.

Your `count` array always has exactly one (`array[0] - array[0] + 1`) element. 
This means that you have undefined behaviour when reading or writing beyond index 0.
(Variable-length arrays are a non-standard extension. Learn how to use `std::vector`.)

You don't know the maximum and minimum values until after the loop that determines what they are has completed.
Move the array declaration after that loop.

Also, you need to fix that loop, because it doesn't necessarily find the minimum value (`array[i] <= max` does not mean that you have found one).
You will have `min == 6` for your example input, for instance.

The counting loop needs to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

because you're looping over `array`, which has `length` elements.

And you need to adjust your counter, since the minimum value corresponds to index 0 but isn't necessarily 0:

```
count[array[i] - min]++;
```

And the "result-gathering" loop should be

```
for (int j = 0;j < max - min + 1;j++)
```

because `count` has `max - min + 1` elements, and you need to

```
array[sum++] = min + j;
```

because the first element counts the `min` occurrences, not the zeroes.

I think that covers most of your problems.

(And a side note: "sum"  is a very peculiar name for something that isn't a sum.)

Comment: I improved my code but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int array[], int length){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                cout << array[i];
                cout << endl;
}


void countingSort(int array[], int length){

        int max = array[length - 1];
        int min = array[0];
        int count[100] = {};
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                 if( array[i] > max)
                        max = array[i];
                 else
                        min = array[i];
        }
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                  count[array[i] - min]++;
         }
         for (int j = 0;j < max - min + 1;j++)
    {
            while(count[j] --)
            array[sum++] = min + j;
    }

}






      int main() {
      int array[] = {4,7,8,9,10,6};
      countingSort(array, 6);
     printArray(array,6);


     return 0;
      }
```

I improve it in some places but not it gives me a output 6,7,8,9,10,6...

Comment: Unfirtunately, I cannot compile your code and manipulate it to find the logic error on my iPad, so its hard to tell where you exactly where you went wrong. However, you can visit this link: http://www.sitesbay.com/cpp-program/cpp-short-array-element-ascending-order . It h some code that you can compare to yours to find the error source.